# Insert integer into char-array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

I have the following char array:

`char* a = new char[6]{0};`

Which in binary is:

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`

I also have an integer:

`int i = 123984343;`

Which in binary is:

```
00000111 01100011 11011001 11010111
```

I would like to insert this 4-byte-integer `i` into the char array `a` from position `[1]` to position `[4]` so that the original array `a` becomes:

`00000000 00000111 01100011 11011001 11010111 00000000`

What is the quickest and easiest method to do that?

Comment: I smell an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish? This probably isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: This is wrong on many levels, since the representation of signed integers is implementation defined, the same is how many bits a char and an int have. A char could be as big as an int. Use unsigned fixed with types, instead.

Comment: How do you know that is the representation of the int in binary.  There are other platforms where it is `1101011 11011001 0110011 00000111`.  There are a total of *at least* six different possible binary representations if the integer is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem *as asked* with

```
    memcpy( &a[1], &i, sizeof(i) );
```

but I bet dollars to doughnuts that this is not the best way of solving your problem.

```
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < 4; ix++)
    {
        a[1+ix] = (static_cast<unsigned int>(i) >> (8*ix)) & 0xff;
    }
```

Is a safe way of serializing an `int` which fits into four bytes into a character array.  Neither this end, nor the other end, have to make non-portable assumptions.

I'm not convinced that even this is the best way of solving your actual problem (but it hard to tell without more information).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `copy` algorithm and a cast to char to access the underlying byte sequence:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>

std::uint32_t n = 123984343;
char * a = new char[6]{};

{
    const char * p = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&n);
    std::copy(p, p + sizeof n, a + 1);
}
```

In this case I am assuming that you are guaranteeing me that the bytes of the integer are in fact what you claim. This is platform-dependent, and integers may in general be laid out differently. Perhaps an algebraic operation would be more appropriate. You still need to consider the number of bits in a `char`; the following code works if `uint8_t` is supported:

```
std::uint8_t * p = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t *>(a);
p[1] = n / 0x1000000;
p[2] = n / 0x0010000;
p[3] = n / 0x0000100;
p[4] = n / 0x0000001;
```

Comment: Argh, yes, `char` is an exception to the strict-aliasing rule... forgot that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it tomorrow!

Comment: Why does the last example not break the strict-aliasing rule?

Comment: @cad: Hm, yeah. I'm assuming that if `uint8_t` exists, then it is an alias for one of the char types. Perhaps that warrants a static assertion. The point is that this code can only work if `CHAR_BIT` is 8, so I wanted to encode that. Alternatively you can use `unsigned char` and assert that that has eight bits.

Answer (score 0):

If int is of 4 bytes, then copy the int to address of 2nd position in the char array.

```
int i = 123984343;  
char* a = new char[6]{0};   
memcpy(a+1, &i, sizeof(i));
```